# Probability of card distribution in bridge

Tags: probability

You are playing bridge and are dealt a hand of thirteen card, What is the probability that there are fours cards in one suit and three cards in each of the other suits?

I don't know much about bridge so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: http://www.bridgehands.com/P/Probability_Hand_Distribution.htm

Comment: You have all you need to know about bridge for this problem.  Your hand has $13$ of the $52$ cards, selected randomly.

Answer (score 4):

There are $\binom{52}{13}$ equally likely bridge hands.

Now we count the bridge hands that have $4$ cards in one suit ($\spadesuit$ or $\heartsuit$ or $\diamondsuit$ or $\clubsuit$)  and $3$ cards in each of the other suits.

The **suit** you have $4$ cards in can be chosen in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways. For **every** such choice, the actual $4$ cards can be chosen in $\binom{13}{4}$ ways. For each of the other $3$ suits, the actual cards can be chosen in $\binom{13}{3}$ ways, for a total of
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{13}{4}\binom{13}{3}^3.$$

For the probability, divide by $\binom{52}{13}$.